# Launch intent for Facebook fan page

Tags: android, facebook

I use this code in an Activity to open a Facebook fan page:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/" + pageId));
startActivity(intent);
```

Today I upgrade Facebook App to 11.0.0.11.23, then it doesn't work.
Any idea?

---

My current solution is to start intent twice. The second intent will start after 2 sec.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the way Facebook handles intents has changed.

If you check out, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/navigation-protocol , 
it says :

Deep-linking on Android is Intent-based, wherein each app can register and define Activities and Intent filters that the operating system will route to that app. Performing an App Link navigation on Android involves constructing an Intent that contains al_applink_data in its Intent extras.

They also suggest the usage of the Bolt SDK and to navigate you might want to check this out : https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#navigating-to-a-url

Edit 1 :

I have never used this but from the github page. Include the Bolt Lib in your android project, then call : `AppLinkNavigation.navigateInBackground(getContext(), url);` Here url is the facebook url of the page. This should automatically launch the required intent.

Comment: Thanks for information, but I still don't know how to use, any example?